# Autocorrelation & Cross-Correlation -> Main uses in DSP??

Tags: phase, modulation, autocorrelation, cross-correlation, correlation

Please help understanding the DSP usage of Autocorrelation & Cross-correlation

It seems this is strongly linked to calculating phase offsets, frequency offset for carrier recovery, symbol timing errors, recovery algorithms, what else?

**What can I get from Cross-correlation? Started list below, please help**

- Biased version can give difference in constant phase offset between
  two signals, useful to rotate one set of symbols back into place.
- Biased version can give The difference in power between the two which
  is useful if I want to get them to the same amplitude.

**What can I get from Auto-correlation? Started list below, please help **

- I think that the magnitude or absolute of unbiased and unnormalised with no frequency offset or error can give me the bandwidth or Symbol rate of the signal on the Y axis where there is the maximum spike.
- The frequency offset can be obtained from the imaginary part of the autocorrelation, how this is implemented to correct the offset in carrier recovery is still alluding me.

Comment: For the autocorrelation, [this post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/78959/how-to-interpret-values-of-the-autocorrelation-sequence/78961#78961) gives some answers.

Comment: As you learn the details, keep the big picture in mind: correlation is a measure of the similarity between two signals.

Comment: I'd recommend moving your lists to answers, and making each answer a community wiki.

Answer (score 3):

In audio, I have used autocorrelation, or something like it, to accurately determine the period and fundamental frequency of a quasi-periodic audio signal; a musical note.  *Pitch detection*

I have used cross-correlation to measure the difference, in time, that a single acoustic signal impinges upon two different microphones.  From that inter-aural distance, we can compute an angular position of that single sound source is relative to the line connecting the two microphones. *Localization*

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the uses robert bristow-johnson (very well) provided, one can use cross-correlation to detect a (known) signal in noise. For more information on this use you can search for "matched-filter" approaches in *Detection Theory*. A personal preference of a related textbook is [*"Fundamentals of Statistical Signal Processing: Detection Theory"*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B019TLS0M0) by Steven M. Kay, but of course you can search in your preferred sources.

Comment: Oh yeah.  Matched filters.  Also for binary or M-ary communication (which is really your first example).  You have a constellation of signals all associated with a message containing some bits (the simplest is, of course, binary which is a constellation of two given signals, one for a `0` and another for `1`.  But you could have a constellation of 16 signals in a 4 $\times$ 4 grid or something like that.  I think we call those *"symbols"* or similar.  Given a noisy received signal you cross-correlate each symbol in the constellation and see which one the received signal resonates best with.

Comment: Exactly the examples I had in mind, thanks for the extra info :).